# If/else statement with an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement

Using an if statement with input from the user and it compare the value with an array list
'

```
var cib = document.getElementById("cibernetico").value;
var ciber = ('ciber','bin');

function validar() {
  if (cib == ciber)
  {
     alert("Gotta !!");
  } else {
     alert("wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <input id="cibernetico" type="text"  placeholder="ci...">
 <input type="submit" value="Submeter" class="button" onclick="validar()">
</body>
```

'

Comment: That (`('ciber','bin')`) is not an array -> `[ 'ciber', 'bin' ]`

Comment: What do you mean by _"compare"_? Check if the input value is equals one of the elements in the array? Is a partial match? ...?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, "cib" is an input and i want to see if the value of that input matches with one of the words in the array. I dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not a valid array syntax. Should be `var ciber = ['ciber','bin'];`
2. It's valid comparison, but it's probably not what you want.

Do you want to check if the element is matching one of the elements of the list?
If so do: `ciber.includes(cib)`

Comment: That should be a comment

Comment: @Andreas You aren't wrong, but making this a comment makes me spend more time on this question

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ciber = ['ciber','bin'];

var cib = document.getElementById("cibernetico");
document.getElementById("inputSubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    validar(cib.value);
}, false);

function validar(valueEntered) {
  if (ciber.includes(valueEntered))
  {
    alert("Gotta !!");
  } 
  else 
  {
    alert("wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="cibernetico" type="text"  placeholder="ci...">
  <input id="inputSubmit" type="submit" value="Submeter" class="button">
</body>
```

You can find more about the `.includes()` function => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: _'"cib" is an input and i want to see if the value of that input matches with one of the words in the array'_